# ReferenceError: $scope is not defined from angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I'm trying to access `$scope` in my `angularjs` (`ionic framework`) controller are getting this error

`ReferenceError: $scope is not defined`

Following is my setup

```
#directive recipe form
angular.module('directive.recipeForm',[])
  .directive('recipeForm', function(){
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       controller: 'newRecipeCtrl',
       scope: false,
       templateUrl: 'templates/directives/recipe_form.html'
    }
  });

#templates/directives/recipe_form.html
<form ng-submit="recipeSave()">
  <input type='text' ng-model='recipeFormData.name' >  
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

#recipe controller
angular.module('ft.controllers.newRecipe', [])
  .controller('newRecipeCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$ionicModal', '$timeout', '$http', 'Settings',function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $http, Settings){

      $scope.recipeFormData={ name: 'sample name' };

      $scope.recipeSave = function(){
         // error from comes here
      }
    }]);
```

And when the form loads it correctly access the values in `$scope.recipeFormData` and set the text box value to 'sample name', but when I click save button, it fires the `recipeSave` method , but inside that I dont have the `$scope` variable

And I do understand that there are lots of SO questions with the same error, and I checked them too. but most of them users controller directly binded to the view, not as a directive.

What I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem of this error is. But in such case (changing context variables: this, $scope etc.) you may "save" them in self variable:

```
angular.module('ft.controllers.newRecipe', [])
  .controller('newRecipeCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$ionicModal', '$timeout', '$http', 'Settings',function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $http, Settings){
  var self = $scope;
  $scope.recipeFormData={ name: 'sample name' };

  $scope.recipeSave = function(){
     //here refer to self
  }
}]);
```

Comment: what if user wants to update the variable inside the function!

Comment: if user wants to update variable properties, i.e. self.obj = sth it may do so. Changing value of self itself (pointing it to other object) does not make sense.